# Is it a known bug with the animate package?

Tags: beamer, animations, knitr, animate

[In slide 10 here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eloo4kbqen9iieb/Slides_extracts.pdf), I have embedded three animations in only one slide. You can see there's a bug by playing with the animations, is it a known bug ? Or is there something special to do in the code for multiple animations on the same page ? Or maybe it has something to do with beamer ?

If this is an unknown bug, where should I report it ?

Comment: We can't see how you created it, so we can't test this? If you suspect it has something to do with beamer, try and create a MWE in article class to see if it re-occurs.

Comment: These are slides generated with knitr. All the animations work well except this bug with the multiple animations on one slide. I know you can't see the code, I'd firstly like to know if anyone has already encountered this problem. You're right, I have never tried outside beamer yet.

Comment: I am sorry, but we still need the code. The manual of animate has two animations in one page, so this suggests that it at least can work. It could even be a problem of knitr, it is hard to tell without more information.

Comment: Ok, but I will first try outside beamer (when I'll be less busy).

Comment: Ok, great! :) Good luck!

Comment: What is wrong with the animations on page 10? I cannot see anything anomalous. What do you expect to see?

Comment: Offtopic: Do I need some particular PDF viewer to have the animate running?

Comment: @AlexG Play with the three at the same time, stop them, run again... there's something anomalous,  hard to explain in English sorry :-(

Comment: @m0nhawk Acrobat Reader

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: Oh, thanks. Never used it on Linux...

Comment: Still cannot see the issue, except for the rightmost anim which doesn't loop (perhaps on purpose or forgotten `loop` option).

Comment: @AlexG I'm using Acrobat Reader 10.1.2. And you ?

Comment: 9.5.5 on Linux.

Comment: Thanks. I hope I will come back this week-end after more investigations.